# Translate validation message in RadDataForm - Nativescript/Angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have this configs for a `RadDataForm`.

```
{
    isReadOnly: false,
    commitMode: "Immediate",
    validationMode: "Immediate",
    propertyAnnotations: [
      {
        name: "name",
        displayName: "name",
        index: 0,
        validators: [{name: "NonEmptyValidator"}],
      }
    ]
}
```

And work fine. But, can I translate the validator message `Entered value cannot be empty`?

I been search inside the docs but, I can't found nothing about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `errorMessage` for each validator, ensure you are passing the right translation.

I presume you must be using `nativescript-i18n` Or some other plugins to keep track of translations in your app, just fetch the right string and pass it to validator.